# В какой вью лучше выгружать большой объем текста в Android?

Tags: android

Нужно написать справочник, что-то вроде шпаргалки. Есть текстовые файлы с html разметкой в res/raw/. Надо брать файл, соответствующий определенной теме и выгружать его во View. Какой View для этого лучше использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Можно делать **ScrollView**, в который класть **TextView**. А текст из файла помещать так:
**Html.fromHtml(text)**.

Comment: `TextView` поддерживает html форматирование достаточно ограниченно - это раз, во вторых его размер ограничен (что-то типа 64 к)